# Tablesorter not fully responsive

Tags: jquery, css, html-table, tablesorter

I can't figure out what's stopping the table from being fully responsive.

[Here is an example of the table WITHOUT TABLESORTER](http://sellingtweets.com/2/)

[and here is an example WITH TABLESORTER added](http://sellingtweets.com/1/)

Notice when you shrink the page on the table without tablesorter it keeps all the columns on the page. When you shrink it with tablesorter the text hits the side of the column then wont shrink any further and then moves of the screen as you shrink the page more.

I can't seem to find what is causing this in tablesorter.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `white-space: nowrap;` added to the widest `<td>` in the tablesorter demo, but not the first demo.

```
<td class="column-2 ui-table-priority-1" style="white-space: nowrap;">Clash with the Black Cat Pirates! The Great Battle on the Slope!</td>
```

If you remove that style, both pages will behave the same.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I cant find 'white-space: nowrap;' anywhere in the coding in the links i gave. Where does it need to be removed from so its not added to the widest td?

Comment: Ok never mind i found it in the JS file. i removed all `'white-space','nowrap'` text and it now works

Comment: Ok so it worked but i think that caused another problem.[here is a sample](http://sellingtweets.com/3/) if you click the 'one piece' link then go back from the back link the sort and search features disappear.